# Magento : How to set up Buy 2 get 3 promotion on a particular sku

Tags: configurable-product, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I wanting to set up a promotion, without a code where customer adds a particular configurable product to their basket with qty 3, then they get the third on for free.

For Exam : Customer add Product A with qty 3, then automatic promotion is applyied.

The product has different sku for the different flavours.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is rather vague, I would say the solution is a a tier price.

What you do is: create a tier in the product page in the backend. At "Qty" 3 you reduce "Price" to 2/3 of the original price.

What version of Magento are you using?